# Linear regression libraries in R

Tags: r

I try to run the following code in R:

```
prop = 0.75
seed = 957
set.seed(seed)
sampled <- sample(1:nrow(propTbl),nrow(propTbl)*prop,replace=FALSE,prob=NULL)

train <- propTbl[sampled,-c(1:2)]
test <- propTbl[-sampled,-c(1:2)]

model <- glm(hit ~ .,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train[])
summary(model)
modelOut <- tidy(model)
```

but I keep on getting the following errors:

Error in tidy(model) : could not find function "tidy"

Error in summary(model) : object 'model' not found

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'hit' not found

Do you know what package and libraries I need to install?

Comment: `tidy` isn't base R. You need to install (if you haven't done so already) and `library()` the relevant package

Comment: This is just a fragment of a larger chunk of code, why not look at the code that you copied this from?

Comment: Unfortunately, the original code does not indicate the used libraries...

Comment: it's from broom, you can also see the answer below

Comment: Does anyone know what packages are needed to be installed for model, hit, prdiction?

Answer (score 1):

tidy() is a function in broom package.

Install "broom" package and load it from library

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Do you know what packages are needed to be installed for model, hit, prediction?

Comment: @TaylorWork everything is available in the base for this model. It does not require additional packages. Refer this tutorial https://datascienceplus.com/perform-logistic-regression-in-r/